# Accessing variables declared inside the constructor

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I have an index file and on click form submit it calls a method in class `Users.php` which  also extends the class `SqlFunctions.php` from the method in User class. I'm calling the function in SqlFunction class. I'm unable to access the variable defined inside the constructor.

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once '../includes/constants.php';
    require_once DOCROOT.'classes/class.users.php';

    $objUser = new Users();

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
        $objUser->userLogin();
    }
?>
```

Class Users.php

```
<?php
require_once DOCROOT.'classes/class.sqlFunctions.php';

class Users extends sqlFunctions {
    function __construct() {
    }

    function userLogin() {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->find()); die;
    }
}
?>
```

Class SqlFunction.php

```
<?php
require_once DOCROOT.'includes/config.php';

class sqlFunctions {

    function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'MYNAME';

    }

    function find() {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->name);
    }

}
?>
```

In the above code one it should've printed `MYNAME` since I've defined it in the constructor.

Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: define `$name` as a member in the class `sqlFunctions`. eg: `private $name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a child constructor does not implicitly call the parent's constructor as well, you have to do this yourself. That is why the $name property of the Users class does not get initialized to MYNAME.
To achieve what you want, call the parent's constructor inside the Users class:

```
<?php
require_once DOCROOT.'classes/class.sqlFunctions.php';

class Users extends sqlFunctions {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

function userLogin() {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->find()); die;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define class attribute in sqlFunctions such as

```
class sqlFunctions {
    public $name;

    // etc
}
```

Because your `Users` class define a new constructor, you need to call parent constructor to set name to `MYNAME`

```
class Users {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: This **may** depend on the version of PHP, but you do not actually need to have $name defined in the parent and/or child class, at least on my PHP 5.5.9 it works without it.